# How can we skip the registration form / part / step of Virtuemart 1.1.9

Tags: joomla, registration, shopping-cart, joomla1.5, virtuemart

We have Virtuemart 1.1.9 and Joomla 1.5.23 but we want to fully skip the registration step or is it required that Virtuemart works in Joomla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to be registered to place orders through Virtuemart. You can configure this in the admin - just go into the administrator and

1. Go to Components | Virtuemart
2. Go to Configuration In the Global panel
3. change "User Registration Settings" to "No Account Creation"

Users will have to input their details every time they place an order.

Comment: doesnt work with this installation. Which templates are affected when this is selected?

Comment: login_registration.tpl.php in checkout folder

Comment: well this template ehre just hides the form but doesnt skip the registration and doesnt redirect to the checkout